# martingales, almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, martingales

I am given a sequence of independent random variables $(X_n)$ with respective laws given by $P(X_n=-n^2)=\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ and $P(X_n=\dfrac{n^2}{n^2-1})=1-\dfrac{1}{n^2}$, and letting $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$ I am asked to show $\dfrac{S_n}{n}$ tends to 1 as $n$ tends to $\infty$. Furthermore I am asked to deduce $(S_n)$ is a martingale which converges to infinity.

For the first part, I tried using the strong law of large numbers but I keep getting $0=1$ which is definitely wrong. Could somebody give me a hint?
Thanks.
Harry

Comment: It <ould be interesting (and helpful) that you describe precisely how you tried using the strong LLN.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Borel-Cantelli lemma to deduce the first part, i.e.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}(X_n=-n^2)<\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can not use SLLN because $(X_n)_{n \geq 2}$ in your case is a sequence of independent but not identically distributed random variables. You can review the conditions of SLLN [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Forms). According to the hint of Morris, I will complete the proof:

$$
\because \sum_{n=2}^\infty\mathbb{P}(X_n=-n^2)<\infty\,,
$$

By first Borel-Cantelli lemma, we arrive that

$$
\mathbb{P}(X_n=-n^2 \quad \text{infinitely often}) = 0\,,
$$

thus

$$
X_n = \frac{n^2}{n^2-1} \text{ eventually, a.s} \,,
$$

that is

$$
X_n \to 1 \text{ a.s}\,,
$$

which implies

$$
\frac{S_n}{n} \to 1 \text{ a.s}.
$$

We also arrive that the martingale $(S_n)_{n \geq 2}$ converges to (positive) infinity since $X_n \to 1$ almost surely.